# Newman html report format got changed once the execution is completed in Jenkins

Tags: html, continuous-integration, newman, postman-newman

I have created few APIs using postman and running using newman tool and htmlextra to generate HTML reports. On my local machine i am able to see the proper format of html, but when i integrate the scripts through CI/CD in Jenkins. HTML report format got totally changes. Please refer the both local html and jenkins html and suggest how to see the proper formatted html newman report in jenkins.

[image: Localhtml Report]

[image: Jenkins HTML report]